# Why aren't Dual Engine Centaurs used anymore?

Tags: engines, centaur, rl-10

The last DEC flew in 2004 (excluding Starliner) on an Atlas II. Why aren't they used today for commercial payloads (again, barring Starliner)? I understand that DEC is more expensive than SEC as it incorporates 2 RL10s, but is that the only reason why it isn't used? Perhaps plumbing complexity or improved rated burn time eliminated the need for it?

Comment: I don't know answer, but maybe starting point would be "why dual-engine Centaur was used  before?" For safety reason (engine-out capability)? Or older RL-10 engines were not powerful enough?